# Hide get method in Joomla 3.1

Tags: web, joomla3.0

I face one problem in my Joomla site in specific URL.

My Current URL is http://index.php/beauty-buzz?cat=Skincare , I just want to remove one of part in upper URl that part is **?cat=** , and i Just want to replace it with single character **/**.

I am using Joomla 3.1.

Answer (score 1):

Enable SEF Urls in global settings in admin panel.

If this is your custom component and you have not created router.php for your component, then you will need to create this file for SEF support in your component.

Check this Joomla documentation page, this might be useful: http://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component